# Python NetCDF4 returns a part of the result

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm trying to parse my NetCDF file with [Python NetCDF4](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/).

Here is how I print my data :

```
import netCDF4

data = netCDF4.Dataset('MYFILE.nc')
variable = data.variables['my_var']

print variable[:]
```

And here is the output :

```
[[[[  0.14626905   0.15073127   0.15702666 ...,   2.16087079   1.85385954
      1.6330229 ]
   [  0.15199603   0.1524792    0.16023833 ...,   2.08785558   1.7945435
      1.53411531]
   [  0.15741037   0.15567663   0.15938567 ...,   1.98954475   1.74069858
      1.46132731]
   ..., 
   [  9.2788887    9.50980091   9.68098545 ...,  31.48118973  32.40645981
     29.94233894]
   [  8.79353142   8.8413229    8.9353838  ...,  32.1477623   31.02648544
     27.81228828]
   [  7.49527025   7.49693298   7.49859571 ...,  31.26473045  29.31586647
     28.24591827]]]


 [[[  0.14930199   0.15448895   0.16149491 ...,   1.79938114   1.54701066
      1.35455298]
   [  0.15029675   0.15359367   0.16234756 ...,   1.68896282   1.43696177
      1.24431944]
   [  0.15308209   0.15446053   0.16128175 ...,   1.56143463   1.31972218
      1.13472533]
   ..., 
   [  9.06274796   9.3060236    9.5291338  ...,  31.62846184  31.67973518
     29.1291008 ]
   [  8.62317753   8.68691349   8.79741669 ...,  31.8617897   30.73691559
     27.1242466 ]
   [  7.4323082    7.4356761    7.439044   ...,  30.26707649  28.77895927
     27.37334824]]]


 [[[  0.14486383   0.15053397   0.1580373  ...,   1.58220649   1.37771237
      1.21789706]
   [  0.14881445   0.1508324    0.1601405  ...,   1.4683634    1.26993716
      1.11644578]
   [  0.1533193    0.15873364   0.1618458  ...,   1.34273946   1.15582407
      1.01318967]
   ..., 
   [  8.90223217   8.90035629   8.73252583 ...,  32.53005219  31.91935349
     28.7775898 ]
   [  8.13422012   7.95513535   7.98284674 ...,  31.12573433  30.1478157
     27.24931145]
   [  6.96614504   6.94814014   6.93012047 ...,  29.86423683  28.73914909
     27.61774254]]]


 ..., 
 [[[  0.24114145   0.23916614   0.25755498 ...,   2.01377511   1.97436833
      1.97307515]
   [  0.24045934   0.24496417   0.26440462 ...,   2.50367999   2.33576465
      2.21460295]
   [  0.27951077   0.29309633   0.29956228 ...,   2.36718488   2.32561803
      2.05150485]
   ..., 
   [  3.00640321   3.27329731   3.54564834 ...,  18.4679985   26.38918495
     24.96532822]
   [  2.99567413   3.15291715   3.30652237 ...,  22.98442078  31.35761261
     33.92588425]
   [  2.77546263   2.85286927   2.91519809 ...,  41.55749512  44.26428223
     43.38713074]]]


 [[[  0.2288377    0.22707555   0.23796105 ...,   2.27481699   2.18916821
      2.13653135]
   [  0.23349886   0.23983689   0.25768572 ...,   2.68985939   2.51502323
      2.37905359]
   [  0.2801531    0.29236022   0.2961545  ...,   2.30413413   2.25314546
      2.01824021]
   ..., 
   [  2.53119516   2.6628871    2.92897105 ...,  19.72961235  29.04187202
     25.78588104]
   [  2.50243235   2.62220144   2.73698258 ...,  25.07536697  35.14706802
     37.07580948]
   [  2.30301142   2.31611371   2.31827378 ...,  45.08309937  46.73181152
     46.26189041]]]


 [[[  0.20954911   0.21473609   0.22343312 ...,   2.62998462   2.43386054
      2.28494501]
   [  0.22019306   0.22859167   0.24688104 ...,   2.32324314   2.16715121
      2.03508973]
   [  0.26845312   0.28306186   0.28679934 ...,   2.11179996   2.00885653
      1.89133275]
   ..., 
   [  2.6847105    2.87929988   3.09413958 ...,  19.82722282  28.60776711
     26.12558556]
   [  2.6023159    2.83243227   3.02930951 ...,  28.37161255  36.661129
     41.15200043]
   [  2.45840263   2.65044808   2.71863174 ...,  45.63036728  46.6840744
     47.9279213 ]]]]
```

As you can see I got just a part of the data. Some data are replaced by `...` I don't know why. Maybe the linux terminal can't print all data or I'm using NetCDF4 Library and my file is a classic Netcdf?

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgsafe.org/5691582954.png) of all my data. You can see that horizontal and vertical scrollbar are very little. So I have lot of data.

How can I do to get all data (like my screenshot) in my python output ?

Comment: You are printing `numpy arrays` and numpy replace values by `...` when arrays are large. Try to cast your arrays to `list` before printing them.

Comment: Oh yeah I used `print variable[:].tolist()` my terminal is on fire ! Thanks you it's works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.array` replace values by `...` when arrays are too large.

Print variable as a list : `print variable[:].tolist()`

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Do you know how can I limit my range to get data from coordinate (Latitude / Longitude) ? E.g : Latitude from 69,95 to 69,05 and Longitude from 335,05 to 335,55 you can see them in my screenshot

Comment: You can try with `variables * np.logical_and(variables > 69.05, variables < 69.95)` but it will replace values out of range by 0 ...

Comment: In the documention I see this : `>>> # now, assign data to levels dimension variable.
>>> levels[:] =  [1000.,850.,700.,500.,300.,250.,200.,150.,100.,50.]` there is no way to use this syntax ? I totally new on numpy